# Ajax not executing on get in Django

Tags: python, ajax, django, google-maps-api-3

I'm getting the "refreshing now" but not the "made it to views.py" or "request". What am I doing wrong? Thanks a mil for your help! Here's my code:

Views.py

```
def coordinates(request):
  print "Request: ", request
  if request.method == 'GET':
    print "made it to views.py"
  return HttpResponse('check')
```

Map.js

```
function refreshData()
{
  x = 1;
  setTimeout(refreshData, x*1000);
  console.log("refreshing now");
  $.ajax({
    url: '127.0.0.1:8000/coordinates',
    type: 'get',
    success: function(data){
      console.log('made it here');
    },
    failure: function(data){
      alert('Got an error dude');
    }
  })
```

(probably not necessary but) Index.html

```
<script src={% static  "map.js" %}></script>
    <!-- Get the map from Google -->
    <!-- Pass the initMap function from the above script as a callback to Google Maps -->
   <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={{GOOGLE_API_KEY}}&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
    <!-- include jQuery -->
    <script src={% static  "jquery.js" %}></script>
```

(Probably not necessary but) urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^go', views.go, name='go'),
    url(r'^rtl', views.rtl, name='rtl'),
    url(r'^coordinates',views.coordinates, name='coordinates')
]
```

Comment: probably url is wrong? try url: 'coordinates',

Comment: are you able to see the ajax call in the console?

Comment: Alexander nailed it! Thanks a mil man!